# Accessing a nested inner class through instance of outer class

Tags: c++

Say I have something like this

```
class Outer
{
public:
    static int m_Out;
    class Inner
    {
    public:
        static int m_In;
        void Display();
    };

};

int Outer::m_Out = 10;
int Outer::Inner::m_In = 25;

void Outer::Inner::Display()
{
    std::cout <<m_Out << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Outer objOut;
    Outer::Inner objIn;
    objouOut.Inner::m_in //Error
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Why is this not possible ? Does this mean I cannot access the class inner through an instance of the class Outer? I know i could grab it with Outer::Inner::m_in but I want to know what my limitations are when it comes to nested class access through instance of outer classes

Comment: @That totally makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that member variable `m_In` is declared `static` it belongs to the `class Inner`, and not to any instance of the `class Inner`.

Consequently, the part of code below is not valid C++ syntax:

```
objOut.Inner::m_In;
```

In order to access it you should have typed:

```
Outer::Inner::m_In
```

Furthermore, defining an inner class doesn't imply that every object of the outer class will have an attached member object of the inner class with it. A definition of an inner class is the rather the definition of user type in the scope of the Outer's class definition.

Comment: please put down the comment that the inner class is a type so I could mark it as an answer. This was initially posted as a comment however removed. This statement cleared everything up for me and hopefully will help others too.Thank you for the detailed answer too

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
class Outer{
public:
    static int m_Out;
    class Inner
    {
    public:
        static int m_In;
        void Display();
    };

};

int Outer::m_Out = 10;
int Outer::Inner::m_In = 25;

void Outer::Inner::Display()
{
    std::cout << m_Out << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    Outer::Inner objIn;
    Outer::Inner::m_In;
        std::cin.get();
}
```

You didn't have to do `Outer objOut;`

Comment: I knew how to access it. I wanted to know the reason why. please put down the comment that the inner class is a type in the answer. That clears everything

Comment: Sorry was late on the comment lol was watching a video on youtube. @40two pretty much summed it up for you.